# Rust unable to build 64-bit RISC-V binary

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I'm trying to build a riscv64gc binary on my desktop computer. I added the toolchain using rustup, and it seems to be compiling but not linking. I don't see a target triple passed, nor is it using the llvm linker? What's going on?

```
$ cargo build
   Compiling rusty v0.1.0 (/home/gonzo/github/vmscript/programs/rusty)
error: linking with `cc` failed: exit code: 1
  |
  = note: "cc" "-Wl,--as-needed" "-Wl,-z,noexecstack" "-Wl,--eh-frame-hdr" "-L" "/home/gonzo/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/riscv64gc-unknown-linux-gnu/lib" "/home/gonzo/github/vmscript/programs/rusty/target/riscv64gc-unknown-linux-gnu/debug/deps/rusty-91e5c79e8b10a398.1icj07kgp6riy6ou.rcgu.o" "/home/gonzo/github/vmscript/programs/rusty/target/riscv64gc-unknown-linux-gnu/debug/deps/rusty-91e5c79e8b10a398.2nds3en7x7harbuk.rcgu.o" "/home/gonzo/github/vmscript/programs/rusty/target/riscv64gc-unknown-linux-gnu/debug/deps/rusty-91e5c79e8b10a398.2v63m1b4etm8s6nh.rcgu.o" "/home/gonzo/github/vmscript/programs/rusty/target/riscv64gc-unknown-linux-gnu/debug/deps/rusty-91e5c79e8b10a398.303kqsurg5oh0riy.rcgu.o" "/home/gonzo/github/vmscript/programs/rusty/target/riscv64gc-unknown-linux-gnu/debug/deps/rusty-91e5c79e8b10a398.3elkuabnsvy95hq7.rcgu.o" "/home/gonzo/github/vmscript/programs/rusty/target/riscv64gc-unknown-linux-gnu/debug/deps/rusty-91e5c79e8b10a398.3r64kd80pqjv10ju.rcgu.o" "/home/gonzo/github/vmscript/programs/rusty/target/riscv64gc-unknown-linux-gnu/debug/deps/rusty-91e5c79e8b10a398.3wgrjsqhbin1mctj.rcgu.o" "/home/gonzo/github/vmscript/programs/rusty/target/riscv64gc-unknown-linux-gnu/debug/deps/rusty-91e5c79e8b10a398.48r3jc0pf6ft3du4.rcgu.o" "-o" "/home/gonzo/github/vmscript/programs/rusty/target/riscv64gc-unknown-linux-gnu/debug/deps/rusty-91e5c79e8b10a398" "/home/gonzo/github/vmscript/programs/rusty/target/riscv64gc-unknown-linux-gnu/debug/deps/rusty-91e5c79e8b10a398.2t6innn061qnfecr.rcgu.o" "-Wl,--gc-sections" "-pie" "-Wl,-zrelro" "-Wl,-znow" "-nodefaultlibs" "-L" "/home/gonzo/github/vmscript/programs/rusty/target/riscv64gc-unknown-linux-gnu/debug/deps" "-L" "/home/gonzo/github/vmscript/programs/rusty/target/debug/deps" "-L" "/home/gonzo/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/riscv64gc-unknown-linux-gnu/lib" "-Wl,--start-group" "-Wl,-Bstatic" "/home/gonzo/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/riscv64gc-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libstd-4d23caece3cfb404.rlib" "/home/gonzo/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/riscv64gc-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libpanic_unwind-bd0597832b931a8d.rlib" "/home/gonzo/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/riscv64gc-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libminiz_oxide-c69f5df8e3069335.rlib" "/home/gonzo/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/riscv64gc-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libadler-d00e403322625f86.rlib" "/home/gonzo/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/riscv64gc-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libobject-894038d69e57102f.rlib" "/home/gonzo/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/riscv64gc-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libaddr2line-75fbaf228f48ce8f.rlib" "/home/gonzo/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/riscv64gc-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libgimli-bff05ee40dca0583.rlib" "/home/gonzo/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/riscv64gc-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/librustc_demangle-409277b88ad09194.rlib" "/home/gonzo/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/riscv64gc-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libhashbrown-b2b20bb543a774ac.rlib" "/home/gonzo/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/riscv64gc-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/librustc_std_workspace_alloc-1487b67180a724ba.rlib" "/home/gonzo/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/riscv64gc-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libunwind-44237576dfb581e1.rlib" "/home/gonzo/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/riscv64gc-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libcfg_if-e990ad0df181d5f9.rlib" "/home/gonzo/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/riscv64gc-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/liblibc-9ba7c5b4ecd18d15.rlib" "/home/gonzo/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/riscv64gc-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/liballoc-b00339818adfcc5f.rlib" "/home/gonzo/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/riscv64gc-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/librustc_std_workspace_core-033865d9c78f3d80.rlib" "/home/gonzo/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/riscv64gc-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libcore-6c4981fd8fe7c5df.rlib" "-Wl,--end-group" "/home/gonzo/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/riscv64gc-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libcompiler_builtins-55f6cd5bd09b4c18.rlib" "-Wl,-Bdynamic" "-ldl" "-lrt" "-lpthread" "-lgcc_s" "-lc" "-lm" "-lrt" "-lpthread" "-lutil" "-ldl"
  = note: /usr/bin/ld: /home/gonzo/github/vmscript/programs/rusty/target/riscv64gc-unknown-linux-gnu/debug/deps/rusty-91e5c79e8b10a398.1icj07kgp6riy6ou.rcgu.o: Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 243)
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/gonzo/github/vmscript/programs/rusty/target/riscv64gc-unknown-linux-gnu/debug/deps/rusty-91e5c79e8b10a398.1icj07kgp6riy6ou.rcgu.o: Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 243)
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/gonzo/github/vmscript/programs/rusty/target/riscv64gc-unknown-linux-gnu/debug/deps/rusty-91e5c79e8b10a398.1icj07kgp6riy6ou.rcgu.o: Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 243)
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/gonzo/github/vmscript/programs/rusty/target/riscv64gc-unknown-linux-gnu/debug/deps/rusty-91e5c79e8b10a398.1icj07kgp6riy6ou.rcgu.o: Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 243)
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/gonzo/github/vmscript/programs/rusty/target/riscv64gc-unknown-linux-gnu/debug/deps/rusty-91e5c79e8b10a398.1icj07kgp6riy6ou.rcgu.o: Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 243)
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/gonzo/github/vmscript/programs/rusty/target/riscv64gc-unknown-linux-gnu/debug/deps/rusty-91e5c79e8b10a398.1icj07kgp6riy6ou.rcgu.o: Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 243)
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/gonzo/github/vmscript/programs/rusty/target/riscv64gc-unknown-linux-gnu/debug/deps/rusty-91e5c79e8b10a398.1icj07kgp6riy6ou.rcgu.o: Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 243)
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/gonzo/github/vmscript/programs/rusty/target/riscv64gc-unknown-linux-gnu/debug/deps/rusty-91e5c79e8b10a398.1icj07kgp6riy6ou.rcgu.o: Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 243)
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/gonzo/github/vmscript/programs/rusty/target/riscv64gc-unknown-linux-gnu/debug/deps/rusty-91e5c79e8b10a398.1icj07kgp6riy6ou.rcgu.o: Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 243)
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/gonzo/github/vmscript/programs/rusty/target/riscv64gc-unknown-linux-gnu/debug/deps/rusty-91e5c79e8b10a398.1icj07kgp6riy6ou.rcgu.o: error adding symbols: file in wrong format
          collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
          

error: aborting due to previous error

error: could not compile `rusty`.

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.
```

I'm assuming that lld *should have been* used. This is my cargo config:

```
[build]
target = "riscv64gc-unknown-linux-gnu"
```

UPDATE: I have a custom linker script now, which makes ld stop complaining, except it can't build riscv64 binaries, because it's the system linker. Is it just me or is the riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu toolchain completely broken? I didn't have any such problems with the other riscv toolchains in Rust.

It's just the single toolchain that actually supports std, which has infected literally every package in Rust, making it impossible to go the no_std route, so here we are.

Answer (score 2):

Which linker was customed? I think we have same problems. Actually, maybe use update-to-date risc-v-toolchain.

```
[build]
target = "riscv64gc-unknown-linux-gnu"
rustflags = ["-C", "target-feature=+crt-static"]

[test]
target = "riscv64gc-unknown-linux-gnu"
rustflags = ["-C", "target-feature=+crt-static"]


[target.riscv64gc-unknown-linux-gnu]
runner = "qemu-riscv64"
linker = "riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc"
ar = "riscv64-unknown-linux-ar"
```

It works well. Static feature is for run on `qemu`.